# Connection between results of two SVDs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, matrix-decomposition

Consider SVD of $M$: 
$$
M = U \Sigma V^\top
$$
And SVD of $N= \ln M$: 
$$
N = U^\prime \Sigma^\prime V^{^\prime\top}
$$
Anyone knows/has seen/can think of any interesting connection/relation between $U$ and $U^\prime$? (Or $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^\prime$? )

Update: Let's suppose that both decompositions exist.

Update2: By relation, I mean not the trivial relation of $\ln( U \Sigma V^\top) \approx U^\prime \Sigma^\prime V^{^\prime\top}$.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

Comment: Given that the SVD of $M$ always exists, $\Sigma$ has only nonnegative elements, and $\ln M$ may not exist (at least not in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$), I wouldn't hold my hopes up, at least not for something similar to what you get with the eigenvalue/Schur/Jordan decomposition.

Comment: Thanks. Very good point! Let's suppose that both decompositions exist. Can we find a relation between the output of the decompositions?

Comment: My point was a bit different. Let's say that there is some neat relation, so something like $\Sigma' = \ln \Sigma$. There is no reason for it to work on some matrices and not on others (because $\Sigma \ge 0$ for all $M$, so $\ln \Sigma$ exists for all nonsingular $M$), and we do know that it cannot work on some of them (because $\ln M$ may not exist). My point here is that SVD "hides" the existence of the function. In his "Functions of Matrices", Higham mentions SVD only in Appendix B and problems' solution, which is another reason I don't expect there to be much of a connection (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\log$ denotes the principal logarithm and $M$ has no $\leq 0$ eigenvalues. Then $\log(M)$ is defined and the columns of $U,V$ are the eigenvectors of $MM^T,M^TM$ and the columns of $U',V'$ are the eigenvectors of $\log(M)\log(M)^T,\log(M^T)\log(M)$.

If $M$ is symmetric with eigenvalues $>1$, then $U=U',V=V',\Sigma'=\log(\Sigma)$. If $M=diag(1/2,3,5)$ then the condition $U=U',V=V'$ is not satisfied.

EDIT: Vedran is right. More precisely, let $f:U\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix function (cf. the Higham's book) s.t. $f$ is defined on $spectrum(M)$. Then $f(M)$ is a polynomial in $M$. If $M$ is diagonalizable ($M=PDP^{-1}$) , then $f(M)=Pf(D)P^{-1}$. If $M$ is symmetric $\geq 0$, then $PDP^T$ ($P$ orthogonal) is a SVD of $M$ and $f(M)=Pf(D)P^T$ is a SVD of $f(M)$ only if $f(D)\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The answer makes sense, but is it provable?

Comment: I mean, is it provable that "if M is symmetric with eigenvalues >1" the thing you mentioned always hold?

Comment: @Daniel In that case, SVD is just an eigenvalue decomposition, so you have $f(U \Lambda U^T) = U f(\Lambda) U^T$, where $f(\Lambda)$ is computed elementwise because $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix. This is how you can define a function of any (orthogonally) diagonalizable matrix; nothing SVD-specific here.

Comment: @VedranŠego So you are saying that it is not possible to happen $f(U\Lambda U^T) = g(U) h(\Lambda) g(U)^T$ (such that $h \neq f$ )?

Comment: @Daniel It is possible, of course: $h(\Lambda)$ can be a symmetric permutation of the elements of $f(\Lambda)$. However, if you choose the elements in decomposition to be in certain (i.e., descending) order, then it is unique, as these are the eigenvalues and we know that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $X$, then $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $f(X)$. All of this, of course, under the assumptions from the answer we're commenting.

Comment: Ref. this last edit: while all of that is correct, there is no reason to use SVD (as the OP wants), which is quite unnatural for the functions of matrices. If the eigenvalue decomposition was used instead, all would remain the same, except we could ditch the condition $f(D) \ge 0$. If that one is really needed, it can be achieved by putting signs in the left or the right orthogonal matrix (but not both!) in the last step, and working with $|f(D)|$ after it. This way, all symmetric/Hermitian matrices such that $f(\lambda)$ exists for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ can be taken into account.